# How to use MEF to allow plugins to override existing functionality?

Tags: c#, mef

I'm using MEF to allow users to extend my C# library. It's working great so far, but right now I'm trying to use it in a way I haven't seen it used before.

The primary use case for MEF I've seen so far is this:

- Application exposes primitive interface (`IPerson`)
- External library uses MEF and primitive interfaces to extend functionality of main library (e.g. `IPoliceman : IPerson`, adds functionality)
- Application then uses `ImportMany` to search for correct `IPerson` depending on what it must do

But I need something like this: Let's say I have a tax calculator that takes a bunch of parameters and returns estimated tax depending on those parameters. I want users to be able to create plugins with MEF that **modify** how those calculations are done. Only one plugin that does this should be able to be loaded at any one time. Otherwise, how do I decide which alternate implementation to use?

So basically, my question boils down to this: Usually MEF allows **adding** implementations of classes and methods. How do I use it to allow users to **replace** an implementation?

Comment: This seems super simple. Just allow one plugin to be loaded, and if none is available use the default implementation. You can then have the user choose in your configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is actually just a different way of looking at the same problem. The answer is simpler than it sounds - for any behavior that you want a client to be able to override, just put that behavior in a plugin.

There's nothing that says you can't write plugins just because you're the author of the application. Put your TaxCalculator class in a plugin, and expose an interface allowing users to write their own tax calculators. At runtime, if you have more than one loaded, favor the one that isn't yours. Out-of-the-box, you will be using your tax calculator plugin, so it will work exactly the way you expect. If the user creates their own tax calculator plugin and drops it in the right directory, you use it instead, effectively allowing them to "override" your original functionality.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! What happens if two plugins are loaded that attempt to override the same implementation. Should I just let each plugin overwrite each others' changes, or should I throw an exception. And if I do throw an exception, how can I detect the conflict in the first place?

Comment: How you want to handle it depends on your business case. Sometimes an exception is a good idea, sometimes you just want to pick one. You can detect the conflict when you load the assemblies. If there are multiple assemblies which export your ITaxCollector interface (even after removing yours from the list), you know there is a conflict.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll have to do some thinking about exception vs. picking one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess you are saying to use `[ImportMany]` *everywhere*, along with code to give preference to non-default parts. Or perhaps you are suggesting to use optional imports with `AllowDefault=true`, with a fallback on a default if the import is `null`. Either way, that seems a bit cumbersome to me. You can just use `[Import]` and build in a preference for plugins *once* in the container setup, as demonstrated in my own answer.

Answer (score 12):

Normally when you try to override an export which is already present in the application, you will get a cardinality exception for an `[Import(typeof(IFoo)]` because MEF expects exactly one matching export to be available.

However, you can put your plugins in a separate export provider and give it priority. Here I do that for a "plugins" subfolder inside the application folder:

```
Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string exeLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(executingAssembly.Location);
string pluginPath = Path.Combine(exeLocation, "plugins");

var pluginCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginPath);
var pluginExportProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(pluginCatalog);

var appCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(exeLocation,"*");
var appExportProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(appCatalog);

var container = new CompositionContainer(
    pluginExportProvider, appExportProvider);

pluginExportProvider.SourceProvider = container;
appExportProvider.SourceProvider = container;
```

The order of the export providers as passed to the composition container determines the priority: if an export is provided by both the plugins and the application parts, then the plugins will get priority.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much sense is going to make, but let me try.

I would make a `TaxCalculatorManager` class.  That class could load all of the `ITaxCalculator` implementations from MEF.  From there, you could have something in the `Export` attribute that would allow ranking of the implementations.  Then when you need to calculate the taxes, you would call `TaxCalculatorManager.Calculate` which would rank the `ITaxCalculator` implementations and call `Calculate` on the winner.

Let me know if you need me to clarify any points.

Comment: As noted by Fuji, if multiple implementations are present, you could allow the user to select the winner.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like the idea of ranking implementations on importance... I'll look into it.